# chatterbot.chatterbot.ChatBot.ChatBotException: Either a statement object or a "text" keyword argument is required. Neither was provided

Tags: python, django, chatbot, chatterbot

so i've been stuck on this for 2 days and i still didn't figured it out, i'm implementing a chatterbot inside my Django project and since there's few documentations for this i didn't find any solution for this issue. To be able to integrate it inside my project i had to downgrade python's version to become 3.7.

my views.py is the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import chatbot
from chatterbot.logic import LogicAdapter
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.conversation import Statement
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer


def index(request): 
    return render(request, "finalTest/index.html")

def give_response(request): 
    userText = request.POST.get('msg')
    print(userText)
    response = chatbot.get_response(userText)
    print(response)
    return response


# Creating ChatBot Instance
chatbot = ChatBot('Mason')

 # Training with Personal Ques & Ans 
conversation = [
    "Hello",
    "Hi there!",
    "How are you doing?",
    "I'm doing great.",
    "That is good to hear",
    "Thank you.",
    "You're welcome."
]

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)
trainer.train(conversation)

# Training with English Corpus Data 
trainer_corpus = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
trainer_corpus.train(
    'chatterbot.corpus.english'
)
```

The input inside my index.html is:

```
<main class="msger-chat">
      <div class="msg left-msg">
        <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/327/327779.svg)"></div>

        <div class="msg-bubble">
          <div class="msg-info">
            <div class="msg-info-name">CoronaBot</div>
            <div class="msg-info-time">12:45</div>
          </div>

          <div class="msg-text">
            Hi, welcome my name is Mason. 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>

    <form class="msger-inputarea">
      <input type="text" class="msger-input" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter your message...">
      <button type="submit" class="msger-send-btn">Send</button>
    </form>
  </section>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js'></script>
  <script>

    const msgerForm = get(".msger-inputarea");
    const msgerInput = get(".msger-input");
    const msgerChat = get(".msger-chat");


    // Icons made by Freepik from www.flaticon.com
    const BOT_IMG = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/327/327779.svg";
    const PERSON_IMG = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg";
    const BOT_NAME = "Mason";
    const PERSON_NAME = "You";

    msgerForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const msgText = msgerInput.value;
      if (!msgText) return;

      appendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "right", msgText);
      msgerInput.value = "";
      botResponse(msgText);
    });
    
        function botResponse(rawText) {

      // Bot Response
      $.get("/get", { msg: rawText }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(rawText);
        console.log(data);
        const msgText = data;
        appendMessage(BOT_NAME, BOT_IMG, "left", msgText);

      });

    }
```

```
The error that appears when i enter a text and click on submit:
```

```
[28/Feb/2021 23:10:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3336
None
Internal Server Error: /get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\finalBot\finalCountdown\finalTest\views.py", line 16, in give_response
    response = chatbot.get_response(userText)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 87, in get_response
    'Either a statement object or a "text" keyword '
chatterbot.chatterbot.ChatBot.ChatBotException: Either a statement object or a "text" keyword argument is required. Neither was provided.
[28/Feb/2021 23:10:46] "GET /get?msg=hi HTTP/1.1" 500 66998
```

app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("get", views.give_response, name="response")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it I would say the error is with your ajax call.

In your view `userText` is most likely empty because there is no `POST` data in your request because you made a `GET` request from your javascript code.

I think you meant to have have used `$.post(...)` instead of `$.get(...)`?

```js
$.post("/get", { msg: rawText }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(rawText);
        console.log(data);
        const msgText = data;
        appendMessage(BOT_NAME, BOT_IMG, "left", msgText);

      });
```

You should probably update your urls.py route to reflect that it isn't a get request but that is purely cosmetic. i.e `"/get"` -> `"/post"`.

Comment: The error disappeared, Thanks. However it isn't working yet, when i open the page i get the following in my terminal:
**[01/Mar/2021 14:59:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3305**
after i send a message from the input my terminal:
**Not Found: /get
[01/Mar/2021 14:59:13] "POST /get HTTP/1.1" 404 2286** 
I have changed my code to the one you provided having in my app urls.py: 
** path("post", views.give_response, name="response") ** 
adding `/post` i get a warning telling that it's unnecessary to add a `/`. 
Any suggestions? Thanks @Danoram

Comment: One more thing, after i send a message, i get in my console the following:
 `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/get 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
r.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:4
botResponse @ (index):93
(anonymous) @ (index):68`

where line 93 is the code you provided me and line 68 is the following: `botResponse(msgText);` in:
`appendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "right", msgText);
      msgerInput.value = "";
      botResponse(msgText);`

Comment: Could you provide your urls.py in the question please

Comment: i will provide the old one to match the initial code @Danoram.

Comment: If you changed your url path to `path("post", views.give_response, name="response")` make you you changed the ajax code to `$.post("/post", { msg: rawText }).done(...);`